# How to slice a 2D array non-consecutively in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My friend `A` is back and she now looks like

```
A = np.array([
    [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0], 
    [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
             ])
```

I need to find the sub-matrix that is `H = A[(1,3,7), (2,3,6)]`. But thats returns

```
array([0, 0, 1])
```

I'm expecting rows 1, 3 and 7 paired with columns 2,3 and 6. I can't seem to find that syntax.

```
H = [[0,1,0],
     [1,0,0],
     [0,0,1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```
A[np.ix_((1,3,7),(2,3,6))]
#array([[0, 1, 0],
#       [1, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: DOH! I forgot about that.  Thanks!