# How to extract multiple rows from tensor at the same time?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

TL;DR:
TensorFlow tensor is of shape `(50, 50, 6)`, want these indices (:, :, (0, 2, 3)). How to extract them?

Here is an example array I am working with:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0,10, (50, 50, 6))
```

I want to extract the the first, third, and fourth row; in other words I need all these entries `(:, :, (1, 3))`, which works for numpy arrays:

```
out = a[:,:, [0, 2, 3]]
out.shape #(50, 50, 3)
```

Working with a tensor `t = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)` and then calling the index like

```
t[:,:, [0, 2, 3]]
```

throws an error:

```
TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got [0, 1, 3]
```

For numpy I have found the following relevant questions, but they naturally focus on numpy arrays:

[How to slice a 2D array non-consecutively in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46227095/how-to-slice-a-2d-array-non-consecutively-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Slicing a numpy array along a dynamically specified axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398708/slicing-a-numpy-array-along-a-dynamically-specified-axis)

Looking at the TF documentation I found `gather_nd` and `boolean_mask`, which I feel are helpful, but I must freely admit that I have not understood the docs at this part. On SO I found this question [How to select elements of a tensor along a specific axis in TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58052967/how-to-select-elements-of-a-tensor-along-a-specific-axis-in-tensorflow), which focuses on single elements; I am looking for complete dimensions (if that's the right wording here).

How can I do the numpy thing in TensorFlow?

Comment: Can you extract every channel by itself and combine them afterwars? Or convert it to a numpy array and then use `out = a[:,:, [0, 2, 3]]` as before?

Comment: If you want the 0,2 and 3rd element of the last axis in the tensor, you can use tf.gather as follows: tf.gather(t,indices=[0, 2, 3],axis=-1))

Comment: @AbhilashRajan your solution is what I've been looking for! If you don't mind then you can write your comment as a complete answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 0,2 and 3rd element of the last axis in the tensor, you can use tf.gather as follows: tf.gather(t,indices=[0, 2, 3],axis=-1))